# Как развернуть два проекта на одной ветке master в github?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Есть репозиторий, в котором есть главная ветка, на которой расположен проект, типа такой конструкции:

- dir1
- dir2
- README
- index.html

Также есть еще одна ветка, в которой есть еще один готовый проект на vue со своей стандартной иерархией.

Каким образом можно задеплоить оба этих проекта с помощью одного репозитория. Где проект на Vue будет по пути '/', а второй проект по пути '/project2'?

Правка 1.
Насколько я понимаю можно просто разместить на ветке master репозитории с каждым проектом в отдельности:

- project1
- project2

Но тогда и пути соответственно будут '/project1' и '/project2', а нужно чтобы первый проект был по пути '/'.

Comment: Вопрос никакого отношения к гиту не имеет.  Нужно правильно прописывать пути и настраивать маршрутизацию... ну может всякие htaccess ещё или что там в качестве сервера

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а каким образом можно маршрутизацию настроить в github-pages? если вообще есть такая возможность или стоит  сделать это другим образом?

Comment: Точно так же, как она сделана на локальном компьютере

Answer (score 0):

> Каким образом можно задеплоить оба этих проекта с помощью одного репозитория. Где проект на Vue будет по пути '/', а второй проект по пути '/project2'?

Для того, чтобы получить каждый проект на необходимом пути, нужно просто воспользоваться gh-pages. Для того, чтобы первый проект был на пути '/', необходимо разместить в репозитории просто весь проект не помещая его в какую-либо дополнительную директорию. Тогда он просто будет рассмотрен как начальная страница и при деплое будет открываться просто при переходе на ссылку развернутого проекта.

Что касается второго проекта, то мы просто уже в первом проекте создаем директорию с названием, которое фигурирует у нас и в пути. Таким образом при переходе по ссылке и при добавлении в адресную строку данного названия, мы перейдем на следующий, необходимый нам проект.